# Is it possible to have multiple ActionBar CustomViews?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I have a simple question.

Is the following scenario possible with the Android `Actionbar`:

- Actiobar Title
- CustomView1
- CustomView2
- Normal MenuItem

Graphical representation:

[image]

What I know is that it's possible to have a custom `Actionbar` `View` by using this method:

```
ActionBar.setCustomView(View v);
```

in addition to that, I know having a title and normal `MenuItems` in combination with a `CustomView` is supported as well.

But **is it possible to have multiple custom Views** (like in the picture above) in the ActionBar, and **if yes, how?**

Comment: You can provide custom layout for each menu item. Just use `setActionView(View view)` method.

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I was looking for. If you write this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create custom layout for your ActionBar menu items and find the menu items to which you want to provide custom layout in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and call `setActionView(View view)` on them.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM_ID);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);     
    ...
}
```